# Remove month and year from this table and use it as a reference table to find out data based on month, quarter, year

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have this table which has following columns:

```
Country_id 
Country_name 
Locality_id 
Locality_Name 
Market_id 
Market_name 
Commodity_id 
Commodity_name 
Currency_id
Currency_name 
Market_type_id 
Market_type   
Month  
Year 
Price
```

I want to remove `Month` and `Year` from this main table and create another table so that I can use the other table as a reference to this table.

so that there are two tables :Table_1-

```
 Country_id 
    Country_name 
    Locality_id 
    Locality_Name 
    Market_id 
    Market_name 
    Commodity_id 
    Commodity_name 
    Currency_id
    Currency_name 
    Market_type_id 
    Market_type    
    Price
```

Table 2:

```
Month 
year
```

I would like to create a hierarchy like:

```
Month -> Quarter -> Year
```

So that I can make a SSRS report in which I can make report based on month, quarter, year. Here is the screenshot of the table:

[image: Image of data]

The problem is I am unable to think a way by which I can achieve this.

---

**sample data set:-**
these are the column names separated by commas
Country_id ,Country_name, Locality_id, Locality_Name, Market_id,Market_name,    Commodity_id, Commodity_name, Currency_id, Currency_name, Market_type_id    Market_type, Month, Year, Price

**And below is data separated by comma**

```
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,1,2014,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,2,2014,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,3,2014,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,4,2014,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,5,2014,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,6,2014,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,7,2014,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,8,2014,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,9,2014,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,10,2014,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,11,2014,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,12,2014,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,1,2015,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,2,2015,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,3,2015,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,6,2015,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,7,2015,50
1,Afghanistan,272,Badakhshan,266,Fayzabad,55,Bread _ Retail,0,AFN,15,Retail,8,2015,50
```

Comment: Are you *really* using SSRS 2008? SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for over 2 years; long past time to have started sorting our your upgrade paths.

Comment: Can you add the expected outcome to your question

Comment: If you remove Month and year from your table, how do you expect to be able to determine the Month/Year that the Price relates to?

Comment: i am trying to find a way to reference month , year using a unique id

Comment: _I want to remove ... create another table so that I can use..._ Why? How does that "improve" anything here? Especially if you struggle with basic sql skills? Your table - as it currently exists - is perfectly usable for reporting. You can probably easily derive "quarter"  from the month value. Why does a 'unique id" add anything useful to your (undefined) goal? I suspect a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.